# When i was click one button of listview another button also click?how can i stop it

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I have a **listview** with so much  button.When i  was click one button of listview another button also click?how can i stop it.

please solve this problem.
Give me any trick how can i stop another button in listview.

this is my code

```
private class MenuItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MenuItem> {

    private static final String TAG = "MenuItemsAdapter";

    public MenuItemsAdapter(Context context, List<MenuItem> menuItems) {
        super(context, 0, menuItems);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final MenuItem   menuItem = getItem(position);



        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    //      viewHolder.half = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.half);
            viewHolder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            viewHolder.description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
            viewHolder.price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);
            viewHolder.add = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add);
            viewHolder.selectedView = view.findViewById(R.id.selectedView);
            viewHolder.remove = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.remove);
            viewHolder.total = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemTotal);
            viewHolder.quantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity);

            view.setTag(viewHolder);



        try
        {






        viewHolder.name.setText(menuItem.name);
        viewHolder.description.setText(menuItem.description);

        viewHolder.price.setText(String.valueOf(menuItem.price));



          viewHolder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                mApplication.createNewCartIfPossibleAndAskIfNot(
                        mActivity, mRestaurant,
                        new MainApplication.OnCreateCartListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCreateCart(Cart cart) {


                                            cart.addOne(menuItem);

                                            updateItemFromCart(menuItem, viewHolder);
                                            updateCart();


                            }


                        });

            }
        });


        viewHolder.remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (!mApplication.isCartCreated()) {
                    return;
                }
                mApplication.getCart().removeOne(menuItem);

                updateItemFromCart(menuItem, viewHolder);
                updateCart();
            }
        });

        }catch(NullPointerException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        return view;
    }


    private void updateItemFromCart(MenuItem menuItem, ViewHolder viewHolder) {


        if (!mApplication.isCartCreated()) {
            return;
        }
        int quantity = mApplication.getCart().getNOfItemsOfType(menuItem);
        if (quantity > 0) {

            viewHolder.selectedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



        } else {

            viewHolder.selectedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        viewHolder.quantity.setText(String.valueOf(quantity));

        viewHolder.total.setText(String.valueOf(quantity
                * menuItem.price));

    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView description;
        TextView price;
        Button add;
        View selectedView;
        Button remove;
        TextView total;
        TextView quantity;
        TextView half;

    }

}
```

Comment: was this meant to be a joke?

Comment: You might doing mismatch between the id of buttons, thats why it happens. Please, Post your code so that we can solve it.

Comment: @pvn i am not joking with you.i am facing so i asked

Comment: then, please post your code fast..

Answer (score 0):

I can think of you are missing recycle adapter implementation with static view holder inside adapter. Again, this is hypothetical answer based on text and my past experience. More detailed investigation requires code study.

---

You can keep null check for your view

```
    final MenuItem   menuItem = getItem(position);
    View view = convertView;
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;

if (convertView == null) {

    LayoutInflater inflater;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
//      viewHolder.half = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.half);
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewHolder.description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
        viewHolder.price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);
        viewHolder.add = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add);
        viewHolder.selectedView = view.findViewById(R.id.selectedView);
        viewHolder.remove = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.remove);
        viewHolder.total = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemTotal);
        viewHolder.quantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
}else{
    viewHolder= (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag(); 
}
```